# Rtsp audio not working video is working

Tags: android, audio, client, wifi, rtsp

I am trying to view a file being streamed from my pc to my tablet.  The video works fine but I cannot hear the audio.

There is no problem with the audio stream as I can hear audio stream on another client on my pc.  The tablet audio is also fine as I can hear other videos being played fine.

Only while using rtsp client, I cannot hear audio on my tablet whereas video works fine.  What can be the problem?
Thanks.

The code being used is this:

```
            mPlayerIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, "rtsp://ip:port/stream");
            startActivity(mPlayerIntent);
```

Comment: I am using file streaming in vlc using all elementary streams.  This is when video is visible otherwise it does not play at all.  Audio does not work in any case.

Comment: I found the issue, the Audio stream was MPEG(Audio), this is not present in the supported formats "http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html".  Changing the audio format to MP4(AAC) made it work.

Comment: is now mp3 supported ? http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html